# How to upper bound the difference between these two Gaussian-like densities?

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, gaussian

$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\cov}{cov}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\supp}{supp}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\dom}{dom}
\newcommand{\diff}{ \, \mathrm d}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\EE}{\mathbb E}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\PP}{\mathbb P}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\NN}{\mathbb N}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\RR}{\mathbb R}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\FF}{\mathbb F}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\WW}{\mathbb W}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\QQ}{\mathbb Q}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div}
$

Let $b:\RR_+ \times \RR^d \to \RR^d$ and $\sigma:\RR_+ \times \RR^d \to \mathcal M^{\text{sym}}_{d \times d} (\RR)$ be measurable. Let $a(t, x) := \sigma \sigma^\top (t, x)$. We assume that

1. There is $\lambda >0$ such that
   $$
   \lambda^{-1} |\xi|^2 \le \xi^\top a(t, x) \xi \le \lambda |\xi|^2
   \quad \forall (t, x, \xi) \in {\RR}_+ \times {\RR}^d \times {\RR}^d.
   $$
2. There is $\eta, L>0$ such that
   $$
   \sup_{(t, x) \in \RR_+ \times \RR^d} |b(t, x)| + \sup_{(t, x) \in \RR_+ \times \RR^d} |\sigma(t, x)| + \sup_{\substack{(x, y) \in  \RR^d \times \RR^d \\ t \in \RR_+, x \neq y}} \frac{|a(t, x) - a(t, y)}{|x-y|^\eta} \le L.
   $$

We define Gaussian-like densities
$$
\begin{align}
p_c (t, x, x') &:= \left ( \frac{c}{2 \pi t} \right )^{d/2} \exp \left ( - \frac{c |x'-x|^2}{2t} \right )
&& \forall c, t >0, \forall x,x' \in {\RR}^d, \\
G(y) &:= (2\pi)^{-d/2} \exp (-|y|^2/2) && \forall y \in {\RR}^d.
\end{align}
$$

Let $x,x' \in \RR^d$ and $h, t>0$. We are interested in bounding the absolute value of the quantity
$$
\alpha := \frac{1}{h} \left ( \frac{G ((\sqrt h \sigma (t, x))^{-1}(x'-x-b(t, x)h)}{\sqrt{h^d \det a(t, x)}} - \frac{G ((\sqrt h \sigma (t, x'))^{-1}(x'-x-b(t, x')h)}{\sqrt{h^d \det a(t, x')}} \right ).
$$

At the end of page 21 of the paper [On Some non Asymptotic Bounds for the Euler Scheme](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.1347.pdf), the authors said that

> ...tedious but elementary computations involving the mean value theorem yield that $\exists c>0, \exists C \ge 1$ s.t.
> $$
> |\alpha| \le C h^{-1 + \eta/2} p_c (h, x, x').
> $$

The authors did not provide these "elementary computations", so I'm trying to derive above inequality.

**My attempt:** Let
$$
\begin{align}
y_1 &:= (\sqrt h \sigma (t, x))^{-1}(x'-x-b(t, x)h \\
y_2 &:= (\sqrt h \sigma (t, x'))^{-1}(x'-x-b(t, x')h \\
z_1 &:= \sqrt{h^d \det a(t, x)} \\
z_2 &:= \sqrt{h^d \det a(t, x')}.
\end{align}
$$

Then
$$
\begin{align}
|\alpha| &=  \frac{1}{h} \left | \frac{G(y_1)}{z_1} - \frac{G(y_2)}{z_2} \right | \\
&= \frac{1}{h} \frac{|z_2 G(y_1) - z_1 G(y_2)|}{z_1 z_2}.
\end{align}
$$

By assumption (1.), we can lower bound $z_1 z_2$.

> Could you elaborate on how to upper bound $|z_2 G(y_1) - z_1 G(y_2)|$?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Is $h$ bounded?

Comment: @IosifPinelis $h$ is a constant...

Comment: If $h$ is a constant, why can't the factor $h^{-1 + \eta/2}$ be absorbed into the factor $C$ in $C h^{-1 + \eta/2}$?

Comment: In other words, my question is the following: For what values of $h>0$ do you want the inequality $|\alpha| \le C h^{-1 + \eta/2} p_c (h, x, x')$ to hold?

Comment: @IosifPinelis You are right! In my context, $h$ is the discretization size step of the Euler scheme, so $h$ is bounded by a fixed $T>0$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis May I ask if you have any idea to derive the inequality?

Comment: Yes, I know how to do this, but the derivation is rather long and tedious. You just group like terms at each step. Begin with $|z_2 G(y_1)-z_1 G(y_2)|\le|z_1-z_2|G(y_1)+z_1|G(y_1)-G(y_2)|$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank you so much for your confirmation! I will try to do it.

Comment: Have you done this?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Unfortunately, not yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}\newcommand\la\lambda$We have
\begin{equation*}
    |\al|=h^{-1-d/2}|g(1)-g(0)|\le h^{-1-d/2}\sup_{s\in[0,1]}|g'(s)|,
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    g(s):=\frac{G((\sqrt h\si(s))^{-1}y(s))}{\sqrt{\det a(s)}},  
\end{equation*}
$y(s):=u-hb(s)$, $u:=x'-x$,
$\si(s):=(1-s)\si(t,x)+s\si(t,x')$, $b(s):=(1-s)b(t,x)+sb(t,x')$, $a(s):=(1-s)a(t,x)+sa(t,x')$.
For $s\in[0,1]$,
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{g'(s)}{g(s)}=g_1+g_2+g_3, 
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    g_1:=-\frac{\det a(1)-\det a(0)}{2a(s)}, \quad
    g_2:=-(b(1)-b(0))^\top a(s)^{-1}y(s), 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    g_3:=\frac1h\, y(s)^\top a(s)^{-1}(a(1)-a(0))a(s)^{-1}y(s). 
\end{equation*}

We have $\la^{-1}I\le a(s)\le\la I$ and hence
\begin{equation*}
    \la^{-1}\le |a(s)|\le\la, \quad \det a(s)\ge\la^{-d},
\end{equation*}
and, in view of [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/447138/36721), $|\det a(1)-\det a(0)|\le\la^{d-1}d\,|a(1)-a(0)|\le\la^{d-1}d\,L|u|^\eta$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    |g_1|\ll|u|^\eta;
\end{equation*}
here and in what follows, $A\ll B$ and $B\gg A$ mean that $A\le CB$ for some real $C>0$ depending only on $d,\la,L,T$ -- given that $h\in(0,T]$. Next,
\begin{equation*}
    |g_2|\le2L\la(|u|+hL)\ll|u|+h,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    |g_3|\le\frac1h\,\la^2 L|u|^\eta (|u|+hL)^2\ll\frac{|u|^{\eta+2}}h+|u|^\eta, 
\end{equation*}
since $h\in(0,T]$.

So,
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{h^{1+d/2}|\al|}{g(s)}\ll |u|^\eta+|u|+h+\frac{|u|^{\eta+2}}h. 
\end{equation*}

Next,
\begin{equation*}
    g(s)\le\la^{d/2}\exp\Big(-\frac{|u|^2/2-(Lh)^2}{2\la h}\Big)
    \ll\exp\Big(-\frac{|u|^2}{4\la h}\Big)
    \ll h^{d/2}e^{-c|u|^2/h}p_c(h,x,x') 
\end{equation*}
for $c:=\frac1{6\la}$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{|\al|}{h^{-1+\eta/2} p_c (h,x,x')}
    \ll \Big(|u|^\eta+|u|+h+\frac{|u|^{\eta+2}}h\Big)h^{-\eta/2}e^{-c|u|^2/h}.  \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
Further,
\begin{equation*}
    |u|^\eta h^{-\eta/2}e^{-c|u|^2/h}=(|u|^2/h)^{\eta/2}e^{-c|u|^2/h}
    \le\max_{w\ge0}w^{\eta/2}e^{-cw}\ll1; \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    |u| h^{-\eta/2}e^{-c|u|^2/h}=h^{(1-\eta)/2}(|u|^2/h)^{1/2}e^{-c|u|^2/h}
    \le T^{(1-\eta)/2}\max_{w\ge0}w^{1/2}e^{-cw}\ll1 \tag{30}\label{30}
\end{equation*}
provided that
\begin{equation*}
    \eta\le1; \tag{$*$}\label{*}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    h\,h^{-\eta/2}e^{-c|u|^2/h}\le h^{1-\eta/2}\ll1,
\end{equation*}
again provided \eqref{*};
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{|u|^{\eta+2}}h h^{-\eta/2}e^{-c|u|^2/h}=(|u|^2/h)^{\eta/2+1}e^{-c|u|^2/h}
    \le\max_{w\ge0}w^{\eta/2+1}e^{-cw}\ll1.  \tag{40}\label{40}
\end{equation*}

Now the desired inequality
\begin{equation*}
    |\al|\ll h^{-1+\eta/2} p_c (h,x,x') \tag{50}\label{50}
\end{equation*}
follows from \eqref{10}, \eqref{20}, \eqref{30}, and \eqref{40}, provided \eqref{*}. $\quad\Box$

---

Without condition \eqref{*}, inequality \eqref{50} will fail to hold in this generality.
E.g., suppose that for all $t,x$ we have $\si(t,x)=I$ and $|b(t,x)|\in[0,1]$, so that $a(t,x)=I$ and your conditions 1 and 2 hold with $\la=1$, $L=2$, and any real $\eta>0$. Suppose also that $x=0$, $|x'|=\sqrt h$, $b(t,0)=0$, and $b(t,x')=-x'/|x'|$. Then
\begin{equation}
    \frac{|\al|}{h^{-1+\eta/2} p_c (h,x,x')}\asymp h^{1/2-\eta/2}\to\infty
\end{equation}
as $h\downarrow0$ if $\eta>1$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate that you take time to write such an elaborate answer.